# Preventing space instead of linebreaks

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

How to prevent space at a line break?

```
a
b
c
```

produces:

`a b c`

I want `abc`.

Comment: `a%`, `b%`, `c%`..?

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj) However, if you wish to not insert these, you most likely have to contain them in some environment within which you adjust the definition of a line-break to mean something else (like `\ignorespaces` or `\unskip`).

Comment: @jon Yes, It can solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Remarks

Let's look into how TeX reads the line

```
a
```

First of all TeX splits the line into tokens. This results in

```
a -> (a)_11   Normal letter
  -> ()_5     End of line character
```

Before TeX begins to read this line of input it is in state *N* (Beginning of a new line), when it starts reading `a` it switches to state *M*. When an end of line character is read AND TeX is in state *M*, then it will be replaced by . (space)

To hide the end of line character from TeX and thus preventing its substitution with a space, insert `%` at the end of a line.

## Examples

Typeset using any `tex` engine (no `latex`!)

```
a
b
c

a%
b%
c
\bye
```

## Output

> [image]